# localstorage vs html5?

Tags: html, local-storage

What's the difference between local/html5 on this page:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jstore/wiki/DefaultEngines

I was under the impression that I could use localstorage on Chrome, but looks like that's not the case?

Some elucidation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those pages are not *very* clear indeed, but digging further into the documentation revealed the meanings of ‘local’ and ‘html5’ engines:

> local = Local Storage – DOM Storage,
>   based on the HTML5 Specification for
>   local storage.
>   [link obsolete]
>
> html5 = HTML 5 – Structured
>   Client-Side Database Storage, based on
>   the HTML5 Specification.
>   [link obsolete]
>
> [note: the provided links are now obsolete; read more on W3.org about [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) and [Web SQL Database](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/).]

([source](http://twablet.com/docs.html?p=jstore#js-engines); as mentioned on the project's main page, docs are currently available on http://twablet.com/docs.html?p=jstore  for the time being.)

About local storage in Chrome: that's not true; the table you linked to only point out the engine used by default in a given browser:

> Does the --X-- denote "Supported" or
>   "Not Supported"?
>  Neither, the
>   "--X--" denotes the default browser [sic! – they actually meant ‘engine’ here]
>   which will be used in the given
>   browser.

A table of engines supported by several browser is on the [Supported Browsers](http://twablet.com/docs.html?p=jstore#js-browser) page. As expected, it says that current WebKit-based browsers (the table seems to be old) support all engines (except of course the IE proprietary one).

Comment: Gotcha, so it's actually just webstorage and websql.

Thanks.